# c++ including .cpp: avoiding multiple definition errors

Tags: c++

I have a project that included a couple of files that are included in others

```
A.h --> B.h means A.h is included in B.h
```

There are a lot of inclusions like

```
A.h --> X.h
B.h --> A.h
B.h --> X.h
```

Which all works fine. Now I have the problem that I need to include a cpp file  ( not my file, cant change anything with it ).
EDIT: There is no corresponding .h file for this .cpp
As soon as I do something like

```
Z.cpp --> B.h
```

I get a compiler error for multiple declarations.
I also tried

```
Z.cpp --> B.cpp
```

Similar result, just less errors ( B.h is included in many other .h files )

How can I include this .cpp?

EDIT: I do understand where the error is coming from, I just wonder if there is some workaround.

Comment: Don't `#include` source files. Compile them separately into object files that you then link together.

Comment: You mean making a library out of this cpp?

Comment: No, just separate compilation of a source file to a single object file.

Comment: And what compiler are you using? What (if any) IDE? How do you build your program?

Comment: gcc and qtcreator. if I dont include it, how does the compiler now that class in the cpp and and its members exist?

Comment: the linker binds the calls to the implementation.  The compiler is text to code (object files)  the headers provider signatures so that the linker can then point calls from one object source to calls in another object source

Comment: just because there currently isn't a Z.h, doesn't mean you can't have one, you just need to write it yourself

Comment: Just a hinch, you realize that you can pre-declare functions (and classes)? And that this is essentially what header files do? If that cpp file contains for example one function void foo(){ some_code; } which you need to use, you can go at the top of the file in which you want it to use, write void foo(); without any implementation and then use it, as long as the cpp file is somehow known during compilation. Would be cleaner if you'd simply write the missing header file on you own, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is basic stuff for C++ software development, I suggest you to read a book for an introduction on how to compile and build a program.

Basically, in C++, you #include *.h files in *.cpp source files,
then you compile each *.cpp file,
then **link** all the compiled files (usually *.o on *nix or *.obj on Windows) into an executable program, or a library to be then linked in a program.

I would consider really bad practice to #include a *,cpp file into another cpp file.

As you are using QTCreator, you should have a project that already takes care of this process.

Comment: The problem is that there is no corresponding .h file for this .cpp. And it is an external file, so it is not possible for em to change anything about that.

Comment: if you are including this cpp in your source list, you can build a header file yourself for this cpp that is simply a copy of the function declarations that you want to forward to the other cpp files.  a header file is just a forward declaration that tells the compiler you will find a method like this elsewhere in the compiled source... so use that method.

Answer (score 2):

If you use QtCreator, then it should build the object files for each source file included in the project.

That's why you get multiple definition errors. You have, say, a source file `Z.cpp` which gets built into `Z.o`. Then you have `Z.cpp` included in `B.cpp` which gets built into `B.o`. Now when the linker tries to link `Z.o` and `B.o` into the executable program, the symbols defined in `Z.cpp` will exist in *both* object files, leading to the errors.

The IDE (QtCreator) will make sure both source files are built and linked together, forming a single executable file. Don't `#include` any source file into another source file (or worse, header file).

The classes, structures, function prototypes and external variable declarations are (or *should* be) in the *header* file that you include. The implementation of the non-inline class or structure member functions and functions are in the source file, the compiler and linker will know how to reference them from the object files.

Answer (score 0):

Given the comments here, I added my own header file. that solved the problem. thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: You should accept an answer, or edit your question, or add a comment. Please don't add an answer to say you solved the problem thanks to other answers.